# Jboss is unable to connect to Apple Push Networks

Tags: jboss, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm using Aerogear Unified Push server to deliver messages to push networks. Into my setup messages are properly delivered into Android networks but they fail to be delivered in Apple. The error seems to occur still on the handling from the back end to the push network.

I've did some googling and it might be related to something on [netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/6700) but I'm not sure. I've included the most relevant log:

```
[0m15:36:05,122 DEBUG [org.jboss.aerogear.unifiedpush.message.sender.apns.PushyApnsSender] (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-1186871307)) establishing the connection for ab358c33-ca7c-4b26-82d9-528f00a2f4c8
at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$FailureWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:113)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newHandler(SslContext.java:903)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:113)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:597)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1387)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:419)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:506)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:478)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
at com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsClient$3.operationComplete(ApnsClient.java:395)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:686)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1276)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:624)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:117)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:465)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$000(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:44)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1387)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1122)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:647)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:506)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:478)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned apple uses https/2 to its end points. The images from Alpine Linux which we use as base for our deployments do not have the necessary libs to support https/2 by default.

The following Dockerfile install the necessary infrastructure to have https/2 in Alpine:

```
FROM alpine:edge

# For nghttp2-dev, we need this respository.
RUN echo https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >>/etc/apk/repositories 

ENV CURL_VERSION 7.50.1

RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssl openssl-dev nghttp2-dev ca-certificates
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual curldeps g++ make perl && \
    wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-$CURL_VERSION.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjvf curl-$CURL_VERSION.tar.bz2 && \
    rm curl-$CURL_VERSION.tar.bz2 && \
    cd curl-$CURL_VERSION && \
    ./configure \
        --with-nghttp2=/usr \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --with-ssl \
        --enable-ipv6 \
        --enable-unix-sockets \
        --without-libidn \
        --disable-static \
        --disable-ldap \
        --with-pic && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm -r curl-$CURL_VERSION && \
    rm -r /var/cache/apk && \
    rm -r /usr/share/man && \
    apk del curldeps
CMD ["curl"]
```

Curl -v should report https/2 enabled as:

```
curl -s --http2 -I https://nghttp2.org
HTTP/2 200
```

I've found this proceedings documented [here](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2016/08/11/curl-with-http2-support---a-minimal-alpine-based-docker-image/)